# C# Array Within Array-of-Structs Losing Contents

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, null

I'm just returning back to C# after an extended period of C++ and Qt. I'm currently stumped by what I would have thought to be a very simple problem.

I have a struct:

```
struct FontGlyph {
    public uint codepoint;
    public byte[] bmp;
    ...
}
```

And an array of such structs:

```
FontGlyph[] glyphs = new FontGlyph[100];
```

Now, I have a couple of functions which set up and modify the fields in the structs:

```
static void ConvertFont(Font fnt) {
   ...
   if (fnt.IsSpaceCharacter) {
       glyphs[idx].codepoint = 0x00FF;
       glyphs[idx].bmp = null;
   }
   else {
       RenderFontGlyph(glyphs[idx]);
       // glyphs[idx].bmp is NOT ok here - it is null!
   }
   ...
}

static void RenderFontGlyph(FontGlyph glyph) {
    ...
    glyph.bmp = new byte[256];
    // bmp is fine here, and can be populated as a normal array
    ...
}
```

This isn't a particularly great snippet of code, however, in the RenderFontGlyph function, I can see that the `bmp` array is allocated correctly yet when the RenderFontGlyph function returns, upon inspection of the `glyphs[idx]` variable, `bmp` is back to null.

I appreciate I'm probably doing something n00bish but its been a while. Am I a victim of garbage collection or am I being stupid? It had occurred to me that the struct was being passed into the `RenderFontGlyph` function by-value rather than by-ref but this also makes no difference!

Comment: `struct`s, when passed by value (which is the default), are being copied, so you're modifying a copy of `glyphs[idx]` in your method and it has no effect on the instance stored in the array. Pass the value by reference to make it work.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, thanks for your comment. I have yet again tried passing as `ref` however when the RenderFontGlyph returns, the `bmp` field is still null - even though it is correctly initialized in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
static void ConvertFont(Font fnt) {
   ...
   if (fnt.IsSpaceCharacter) {
       glyphs[idx].codepoint = 0x00FF;
       glyphs[idx].bmp = null;
   }
   else {
       glyphs[idx] = RenderFontGlyph(glyphs[idx]);
       // glyphs[idx].bmp is NOT ok here - it is null!
   }
   ...
}

static FontGlyph RenderFontGlyph(FontGlyph glyph) {
    ...
    glyph.bmp = new byte[256];
    // bmp is fine here, and can be populated as a normal array
    ...

    return glyph;
}
```

or use `ref` like this: `static void RenderFontGlyph(ref FontGlyph glyph)` and then call it like this: `RenderFontGlyph(ref glyphs[idx])`

Comment: Really it just shouldn't be a `struct` in the first place.  It's conceptually a class, and should be implemented as such.

Answer (score 4):

> It had occurred to me that the struct was being passed into the RenderFontGlyph function by-value rather than by-ref but this also makes no difference!

Well yes, it does. You're creating a *copy* of the struct, and passing that into `RenderFontGlyph`. Any changes made to that copy don't affect anything else.

If you pass it by reference instead, it *will* make a difference, because you'll be modifying the original storage location in the array:

```
RenderFontGlyph(ref glyphs[idx]);

...

static void RenderFontGlyph(ref FontGlyph glyph)
```

Or you could keep using a value parameter, and make `RenderFontGlyph` return the modified value which you'd need to store back in the array, as per Leonardo's answer.

I certainly wouldn't go so far as to say that you're being *stupid*, but it's really, really important that you understand the [semantics of reference types and value types](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html), *particularly* if you're creating mutable value types. (And worse, a mutable value type containing a reference to a mutable reference type - the array in this case. You can mutate the array without mutating the struct... this could all become very confusing if you're not careful.)

Unless you have a really good reason to create mutable value types, I'd strongly advise against it - just like I'd also advise against exposing public fields. You should almost certainly be modelling `FontGlyph` as a class - it doesn't feel like a natural value type to me. If you *do* want to model it as a value type, then rather than passing in a `FontGlyph` at all, why not just pass *in* the code point you want to render, and make the method return the glyph?

```
glyphs[0] = RenderGlyph(codePoint);
```

---

As you're claiming that pass-by-reference isn't working for you, here's a complete example demonstrating that it *does* work. You should compare this with your code to see what you're doing wrong:

```
using System;

struct FontGlyph 
{
    public uint codepoint;
    public byte[] bmp;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FontGlyph[] glyphs = new FontGlyph[100];
        RenderFontGlyph(ref glyphs[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(glyphs[0].bmp.Length); // 10
    }

    static void RenderFontGlyph(ref FontGlyph glyph)
    {
        glyph.bmp = new byte[10];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, I will give that a try. Obviously, something is a-miss

Comment: @weblar83: "passing by ref makes not a jot of difference" - that's not true. See my updated answer for a complete example that proves that it *does* work. We can't see what you've tried to do, so we don't know where the problem is, but `ref` works fine.